# Attached files rights for Drupal

Tags: file, drupal

on my website i have two types of files that end users can download - one of them are available for all visitors, and second is only for registered users (users that are logged in).

setting of drupal allows to set only if files are available for all users or only for users that are logged in.

how can i achieve that some files are public and some not?

thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: What are you using to attach files? Upload Module or Filefield Module? Or some other module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: you're using Drupal 6.

If you're using the upload module to attach files to your nodes: consider using http://drupal.org/project/private_upload

If you don't mind creating manual links to the files in your Node bodies (and uploading the files yourself to the private folder) consider http://drupal.org/project/private_download

If you're using filefields consider using http://drupal.org/project/filefield_private

Some up these modules have hardly an uptake (click on the usage statistics link on each of the above links I've shared with you).

Unfortunately mixing private and public downloads is a known area of weakness for Drupal 6. Drupal 7 has fixed this.